# An idea for an implicit context-dependent operator . (dot) as syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, syntax

Some operations in C# seem needlessly bulky compared to other languages. For example lambdas:

```
students.GroupBy(student => student.State).Where(student => student.Count > 1).OrderByReversed(studentGroup => studentGroup.Count);
```

This could be shortened by using really short variable names:

```
students.GroupBy(s => s.State).Where(s => s.Count > 1).OrderByReversed(sg => sg.Count);
```

But this way the variables are hard to understand outside of the context. A way to shorten it even further is to simply skip the single-parameter listing entirely, and have the parameter be implied by the dot:

```
students.GroupBy(.State).Where(.Count > 1).OrderByReversed(.Count);
```

To me this is a bit more readable than either of the above. It would apply for single-parameter lambdas only and of course it's meaning is inferred from context.

**Edit:** for lambdas where the parameter itself is used directly '.' could be used as a direct placeholder:

```
var lines = text.Split("\n").Where(line => line != "");
```

Could be shortened a bit using:

```
var lines = text.Split("\n").Where(. != "");
```

Another place this sort of inferrant operator could be used is in Enum passing. Often the name of the enum is passed too much when it is obvious from context which it is. For example working with OpenTK (a C# implementation of OpenGL), creating a simple textures requires calling something like this every time:

```
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bd.Width, bd.Height, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte, myPointer);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
```

(Note that OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat has to be passed with the full name since it conflicts with System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat; using the dot notation this is no longer necessary)

This contains a lot of enum callings which in the equivalent C++ implementation are much shorter, and thus easier to read at first glance. We could try to skip the enum names, and have them be inferred from the context (the called method's parameter type):

```
GL.TexImage2D(.Texture2D, 0, .Rgba, bd.Width, bd.Height, 0, .Bgr, .UnsignedByte, myPointer);
GL.TexParameter(.Texture2D, .TextureMinFilter, (int).Linear);
GL.TexParameter(.Texture2D, .TextureMagFilter, (int).Linear);
```

This is not only short but it's even shorter than the C++ equivalent, easy to read while preserving the strongly-typed nature of the language. I'm sure there are other places where it could be used, these are just some examples of syntax I'd love to see in some future C# version. What do you think, would it be a good idea?

Comment: Let's call it what it is, a `with` statement...

Comment: The OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat problem can be solved with a type alias, just do something like `using GlPixelFormat = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat; `

Comment: @Henk Holterman a with() statement only works on 1 enum or 1 object, in the examples above I'm implicitly referring to multiple enums and variable names without ever naming them. Try to implement either of the above codes using with() and you'll see it's nothing like what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first example, suppose we see

```
(x,y) => .z + .q;
```

Is `z` a member of `x` or of `y` ?  What if both `x` and `y` have a member called `z` ?

Comment: The OP stated that `It would apply for single-parameter lambdas only and of course it's meaning is inferred from context.`

Comment: as Jakob stated that would not be allowed. Where ambiguity might arise however is for example nested lambdas, but this is no different than conflicting class names in different namespaces - you simply use the full name of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much this is a question, but I'll try to put my two cents in.

The one feature I missed from VB is the `[With][1]` statement. It sure can lead to horrible messes (just imagine what nested `With`'s do) but it did save a few keystrokes, and also made the code more visually explicit (in a sence that "this is where I set the properties of the SqlConnection object"). Then came Object Inicializers in C# 3, a similar (and better designed) feature and they usually suffice for most `With` scenarios.

The C# team has been wonderfull in making the developers focus on the `what` instead of the `how`, removing superfluous syntax all over the place. "lambda"'s existed in C# 2, only they were called anonymous delegates, and their syntax was something like:

```
itemTypes.Find(delegate(ItemType itemType) { return itemType.Name == typeName; });
```

which in c# 3 was shortened to

```
itemTypes.Find(itemType => itemType.Name == typeName);
```

This is just one example in how the syntax was streamlined to be easier and more obvious to use, and that increased the visibility of the feature. I don't know many developers who used, or even knew how to use anonymous delegates, but now, it's expected that any C# developer worth his salt should be comfortable with lambdas.

Now, looking at your proposed features, let's weight the pros and the cons (from a developer perspective, not from a language design perspective):

Pro:

- Shortness of syntax
- Increased ease of use in most usage scenarios
- Implicit gain => Easier to train new disciples in the dark art that is C#

Con (lambdas):

- Confusion in two or more parameter methods (this can be solved by, well, making it illegal for two parameter methods)
- Confusion in nested lambdas (this is the same issue with nested `with`'s - it's just a bad practice)

Con (Enums):

- Enums are not really strongly typed, so this might blow up in some scenarios (this is just a feeling, don't have an example)

---

Bottom line, I would like to see this feature in the case of the lambdas, but it feels a bit iffy in the case of the enums.

Bottomer line, I don't think that there is a real benifit to this feature to justify the change in syntax, so It probably wont be implemented soon (if ever). Tuples and extension properies are still my favorite non-existant features of C#.

Comment: "Confusion in two or more parameter methods (this can be solved by, well, making it illegal for two parameter methods)" - The no-parenthesis lambda-notation `Where(s => s.Length > 0)` instead of `Where((s) => s.Length > 0)` also only works for single parameter lambdas, yet people welcome it. It would be the same with this - a particular short format used in 90% of cases.

Comment: @manixrock: Yes, and also most of the lamdas used **are** single parameter lambdas, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: "Confusion in nested lambdas (this is the same issue with nested with's - it's just a bad practice)" - there's also confusion with same class names in multiple namespaces, and it's easy to solve by using the full name whenever this happens. But in most cases it doesn't, and that's where the advantages comes from. I'd say most lambdas as as short as `Where(s => s.Length > 0)`, and it would be nice to just write `Where(.Length > 0)`.